# replacing null declaration with Optional java

Tags: option-type

I'm having hard time with understanding of Optional class.
So, I have a task where I need to replace every **null initialization** with **Optional** class.

e.g.

I have a class **Client**

So I made object like this:

Client chosen = null;

How am I supposed to replace that null initialization with Optional?

Answer (score 5):

Your initialization could look like the following:

```
Optional<Client> chosen = Optional.empty();
```

or if you want to assign an initial value:

```
Client client = new Client();
Optional<Client> chosen = Optional.of(client);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two simple solutions to initialize the Optional in your case:

1. Initialize the Optional directly to empty, as described by
   cwschmidt:

   ```
   Optional<Client> chosen = Optional.empty();
   ```
2. Initialize the Optional, after the POJO has been initialized or not:

   ```
   Optional<Client> chosen = Optional.ofNullable(client)
   ```

   --> If client is null, the Optional chosen will be inititialized to empty, and if client has a value it will be initialized.